# iTunes connect - Where can I see the crash reports for TestFlight builds?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, crash-reports, testflight

I have an app being tested via TestFlight on iTunes connect. One of the test devices keeps crashing and I'm pretty sure that there should be crash logs on itunes connect but I can't find any on my testflight builds. Does anyone know where they can be found?

Answer (score 1):

It is simply not possible for Betas, check [here](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2014/06/testflight/) for more information, this is the important part:

[image: supporting image containing explanation]

Hope that helps :)