# How to retrieve crash logs from TestFlight app in Pre-release testing

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I've been trying to get crash reports for my app that is being distributed through iTunes Connect/TestFlight, but am unable to locate them.

[I found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408003/test-flight-beta-testing-xcode-6-3-beta-4-does-not-show-crashes) which states you need to "Include app symbols for your application" whilst submitting to iTunes Connect, which I have done. [I then read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368392/itunes-connect-where-can-i-see-the-crash-reports-for-testflight-builds) which states it is only for apps that have been released on the App Store, and does not store crash reports for apps in Pre-release (which mine is).

So, to recap, I have tried:

- Making sure the "Include app symbols for your application" is checked,
- Installing Xcode 6.3 to view the crash organisation screen,
- Waiting ~1 week for crash logs to appear,
- Searching in iTunes connect for the app's crash logs.

Is the only way to get crash reports to install a third party reporting tool like Crashlytics, or am I doing something wrong/missing a step?

Comment: I was searching for more details but still I have questions. Can I remove the testFlight sdk, which is not relevant anymore I guess. The only prerequisite is "Making sure the "Include app symbols for your application" is checked" ? No need to register a custom exception handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I have just started getting crash reports for the app in Xcode's crash logs Organizer. This is probably because of two reasons:

1. I installed Xcode 6.3 via the AppStore, and that fixed any bugs that might have been lying around in the 6.3 beta 4.
2. I built the app using 6.3 and distributed it using 6.3, which adds some magic sauce. I did the distribution process exactly the same way as before, so seems the logical explanation.

However, ironically, I installed the new [Crashlytics from Fabric](https://get.fabric.io) which I have found to be really, really, really good. It has given me far more in-depth information than Apple's crash logs (your milage may vary). I'll keep using it throughout our apps development, but may then take it out once it goes into production.

Comment: I see that TestFlight says 'Diagnostics and usage information may be delayed by up to 72 hours.' Perhaps that was also a factor?